# dangling pointer in managed c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper

I have several unmanaged c++ classes that reference each other. In order to avoid dangling pointers when an instance is released, I'm using boost smart pointers, mostly shared_ptr. So far so good.

However I also have a wrapper in C++/CLI, in which almost every unmanaged class has its managed equivalent to expose it to .NET applications. The wrapper is quite simple, however I was forced to use an unsafe pointer to reference UnmanagedClass* from ManagedClass. I cannot use boost::shared_ptr as a member of ManagedClass, because the CLR does not support unmanaged types as class members (only pointers to them).

Example: class Car which contains 4 instances of class Wheel. Each of the 5 unmanaged instances have 5 managed equivalent instances. Unmanaged Car might need to change its wheels, it deletes 4 instances of unmanaged Wheel and creates 4 new ones. Managed Car asks for the new unmanaged Wheel to create 4 new managed instances of Wheel.

However, the 4 old managed instances of Wheel are still in scope in the managed world, and now contain a dangling pointer to the old unmanaged instances. Any ideas how to realize that the native equivalent of a wrapper was disposed? An easy task with smart pointers. Can I use them in managed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use internal instance counting? Create a base native class:

```
class Base
{
    int refCount = 0;

public:
    void AddRef() { refCount++; }
    void Release() { refCount--; if (refCount == 0) delete this; }
}
```

Then use it as a base class for all of these and remember to call AddRef when you acquire an instance of class and Release() when you no longer need it (for example in destructor). You would have to do the same in you C++/CLI classes; implement a IDisposable interface and clean the held native class instances in the Dispose() method. It shouldn't be much problematic to use, because you only would have to call AddRef once inside constructors and Release once inside destructors/Dispose.

Comment: i am already keeping a refcount (boost is doing it for me) in the native code, with the shared_ptr smart pointer. of course i cannot start another count. my problem is that i cannot use the same boost::shared_ptr from native c++ in c++/cli (or i cant figure out how). CLR does not support unmanaged types as class member variables. you can have a pointer to NativeClass* but not boost::shared_ptr<NativeClass>.

Comment: And this is precisely why I suggested, that you implement a reference counting mechanism on your own, instead of using boost::shared_ptr. This way you will always be able to call Release() from managed code.

Comment: thanks for your help. but how does this solve the dangling pointer issue? let's say Release() gets called from the native code itself (not from the managed code), and refCount reaches zero, delete this. native code is fine. but the managed counterpart still has a dangling reference to the deleted native class.

Comment: If managed counterpart acquired the reference, it should have called AddRef then. In such case if native code calls Release(), the refcount would reach 1 and the class would remain intact. In fact, you may be able to implement your own "safe pointer", which would serve as a wrapper for the native pointer and would call AddRef in constructor and Release() in Finalize() or Dispose() method (if you can determine the exact moment, when the pointer is no longer needed).

Comment: I meant of course, that you would be able to implement your own *managed* "safe pointer".

Comment: references can be copied around. this does not call AddRef()...  shared_ptr increases increases the reference count automatically.

Comment: Your own mechanism would require manual calling of AddRef and Release (as it is done, for example, in COM objects).

Comment: will have to do it if there is no alternative. but my problem here is re-inventing the wheel. (the wheel has been a multi-purpose metaphor today :))